# Setting the IP of connection C#

Tags: c#, web, connection, ip

I have a web browser in my application and I want to change the IP of the incoming connection that's about to load the page. How would I set the connection's IP address? I've done it before in Java but I have no idea on how to do it in C#.

Here is how I'm making the the new IP in Java and setting it to open the page using that IP in Java:

```java
InetSocketAddress newIP = new InetSocketAddress(
    InetAddress.getByAddress(
        next, new byte[] {Byte.parseByte(bts[0]), 
        Byte.parseByte(bts[1]), Byte.parseByte(bts[2]), 
        Byte.parseByte(bts[3])}
    ), 
    80);

URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
url.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, newIP));
```

Now I just need to recreate this in C#.

Comment: Can you show us what you have started in C#? What of the many .net/3rd party classes do you want to use to make connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the proxy address, you can do it on the WebRequest:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888");
        wr.Proxy = proxy;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Or, if you need to set it application wide, you can set the `GlobalProxySelection.Select` to your proxy and all subsequent HTTP requests will use that proxy:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888");
        GlobalProxySelection.Select = proxy;

        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```